# In Scala, why can I use `Unit` as return type here?

Tags: java, scala, types, functional-programming, type-inference

The codes are below:

```
scala> def f(x:Int => Unit):Unit = 1
<console>:7: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses
       def f(x:Int => Unit):Unit = 1
                                   ^
f: (x: Int => Unit)Unit

scala> f(_=>2);
<console>:9: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses
              f(_=>2);
                   ^

scala> f(_=>List(1,2));
```

All three expressions above worked in REPL(with some warnings), but they look a bit confusing..

In the first expression, `f`'s return type is `Unit`, which is the subtype of `AnyVal` but not the Supertype of `Int`, therefore, I can't understand why `1` can be used as the returned value.

In the second expression, `_=>2` also used `2` instead of `Unit` as the returned value, which conflicts with the definition.

In the third expression, `_=> List(1,2)` even uses `List`, subtype of `AnyRef` as the returned value, but the REPL still doesn't complain about this..

Does anyone have ideas about why `Unit` can tolerate the non-subtype type conversion here? Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can use `-Ywarn-value-discard` to be warned about this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Scala will automatically insert `()` (the singleton `Unit` value) in this case to make the typechecking work.  So what you have is equivalent to:

```
def f(x:Int => Unit):Unit = { 1; () }
```

This is known as "value discarding" in Scala.  From the [spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-discarding):

> Value Discarding
>
> If `e` has some value type and the expected type is `Unit`, `e` is converted to the expected type by embedding it in the term 
>   `{ e; () }`

Like in many programming languages, this is meant to facilitate just "throwing out" the return value of the expression.  This allows you to make a method of type `Unit` that only uses the side effects of an expression.

Answer (score 2):

Check [implicit conversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf#page=104) section in SLS

> **ValueDiscarding.**
>   If e has some value type and the expected type is Unit, e is converted to the expected type by embedding it in the term {e; () }.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the answer of Ben Reich:

Conceptually, in Scala the type `Unit` is the super type of every other type. Therefore, every value, including `Int`, is assignable to `Unit`. Effectively, if used as a return type of a method, the compiler will throw away the result value, giving the method the JVM/Java `void` type.

`Nothing` is the exact opposite, by the way: Conceptually, it is a subtype of every other type. Since no instance of `Nothing` exists, no instance of any other type can therefore be assignment compatible with `Nothing`.

Java's `void` somehow is an incomplete mix of both of those.

Comment: Are you mixing up `Unit` with `Any`?

Comment: @acjay No. That's the concept of Unit and Nothing. It wasn't invented by Scala; many strongly typed functional languages have the same concept. The names can be different sometimes, for example Nothing might be called Bottom.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but now I upvoted you to bring you even again :)

Comment: Oh, thanks. :-) I wasn't under the impression that you did the downvote.

Comment: This is not correct. `Unit` is *not* the super-type of every other type. `Unit` is a sub-type of `AnyVal`, which is a very limited set of types. See the [scaladocs for Unit](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Unit). It's not that you're assigning `Int` to `Unit`, it's that the compiler is simply discarding the `Int` value entirely, by inserting `; ()`.  It might be different in other languages, but that's not the way it is in Scala.

Comment: @m-z Oh, interesting. I stand corrected. Thank you!