# In Scala why we need "=" while defining a method?

Tags: function, scala, functional-programming

Following is how we define function is scala

```
def printName() : Any = { println ("vikrant") } 
def printName() : Unit = { println ("vikrant") }
```

Is "=" just a syntax or it has a purpose? Asking this because I am allowed to skip this when I do not mention the return type , like following

```
def printName() { println ("vikrant") }
```

Comment: `=` is needed only when you need to return a value.

Answer (score 6):

If a method returns `Unit`, you can omit the `=` (known as *procedure syntax*), but this is highly discouraged (it has been deprecated and there has even been discussion to [remove it](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7605)).  From [the style guide in the docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html):

> Methods should be declared according to the following pattern:

```
def foo(bar: Baz): Bin = expr
```

> *Procedure Syntax*: Avoid the procedure syntax, as it tends to be confusing for very little gain in brevity.

```
// don't do this
def printBar(bar: Baz) {
  println(bar)
}
// write this instead
def printBar(bar: Bar): Unit = {
  println(bar)
}
```

There is no difference in the generated byte code.  It's just syntactic sugar.  See section 4.6.3 of [the Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), where it says:

> Special syntax exists for procedures, i.e. functions that return the
>   `Unit` value `()`.  A procedure  declaration  is  a  function  declaration  where  the  result  type  is  omitted.
>   The result type is then implicitly completed to the
>   `Unit` type.

So it's compiled to the same code.  This feature has a warning associated with it, if you use the `-Xfuture` option:

> warning: Procedure syntax is deprecated. Convert procedure `foo` to method by adding `: Unit =`.

In Scala, every method returns a value (unlike other languages that have methods that are `void` and do not return anything).  Methods that are `void` in other languages often return `Unit` in Scala (like your `printName` example).

You can declare any method as returning `Unit`, regardless the value of the expression after the `=`.  This is a language feature known as *value discarding*, explained more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28564371/1223622).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I really want to understand is that does it makes difference in bytecode we get if we skip the "=" ? If it is not... then it is a good practice... but also a ceremony for many others.

Comment: I've added a bit more to address this concern, but no – it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Vikrant I've had compilers complain if I omit the equals sign. Even if it doesn't make a difference in the execution of the code, the language seems to prefer using the equals sign.

Comment: @Carcigenicate can you share the warning/error message when you compile this code? On REPL I am not getting any warning .
I am running 2.11.5 .

Comment: @vikrant I don't know exactly what version it was unfortunately. I had to uninstall eclipse due to me running out of space on my tablet. It would have been whatever compiler the latest version of Scala Eclipse comes with. The gist of it was "function definitions without a `=` are deprecated and may result in a error in the future" (paraphrase).

Comment: If you use options `-Xfuture -deprecation` this appears int he REPL

Answer (score -2):

Probably to fit into functional style. Scala seems to lean functional when possible, and curly braces are used to create an imperative block, which leans away from functionality. It's a similar syntax to languages like Haskell where you typically define functions instead of procedures.

The many ways that it can be written is a result of mixing two very different paradigms.

Comment: disagree that curly braces are necessarily imperative. A trivial e.g.: `val xPlus1Squared = { val xPlus1 = x +1;  xPlus1 * xPlus1 }`

Comment: @TooTone True, if you need to bind a variable in an otherwise single statement function, you'll need to use curly braces. It's still 2 statements being executed 1 after the other though, even if your intent was to create a functional function. Another result of mixing 2 different language types. Ideally, to go fully functional style we'd have `where`/`let` bindings, but for whatever reason, they weren't included. Probably because the 2 statement functions gets the job done